# How to pragmatically check with bash script if a branch in git needs to be rebased?

Tags: git, bash, rebase, git-rebase, git-bash

I'm working on a bash script for my team to enforce regular rebasing of working branches.  The problem I am facing at the moment is how to determine whether a branch is behind master and/or if it needs to be rebased, rather than blindly attempting to rebase the branch.

Here is a simplified version of what I have so far:

```
#Process each repo in the working directory.
for repo_dir in $(ls -1); do
    # if working branch is clean ...

        # BEGIN update of local master
        git checkout master
        git fetch origin
        git merge remotes/origin/master
        # END update of local master

        for sync_branch in $(git branch | cut -c 3-); do
            if [ "$sync_branch" != "master" ]; then
                # BEGIN rebase working branch
                git checkout $sync_branch
                git rebase master
                # Do NOT push working branch to remote.
                # END rebase working branch
            fi
        done
    fi
done
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I think there's no need for that. `git rebase` should check that and turn itself into a no-op ("Current branch <branchname> is up to date.") if the branch has the head of master in its commit log.

Comment: @PSkocik My reason for wanting to do this is other than `git rebase`'s ability to self-check.  There are other actions that I want my script to perform depending on whether or not a rebase was needed.

Comment: I think this makes sense. My use-case is that we can't do `git rebase` if there are unstashed/unstaged changes, so it's nice to explicitly check before doing the command for scripts/Makefiles.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To tell if you need to rebase your branch, you need to find out what the latest commit is and what was the last commit that your two branches share.

To find the latest commit on the branch:

```
git show-ref --heads -s <branch name>
```

Then to find the last commit that your branches have in common:

```
git merge-base <branch 1> <branch 2>
```

Now all you need to do is find out if these two commits are the same commit.  If they are, then you don't need to rebase.  If they are not, a rebase is required.

Example:

```
hash1=$(git show-ref --heads -s master)
hash2=$(git merge-base master foo/bar)
[ "${hash1}" = "${hash2}" ] && echo "OK" || echo "Rebase is required"
```

Though as stated in the comment, if you attempt to rebase a branch that is already up to date.  Git will gracefully handle the situation and exit.

Comment: This seems to work when the local master is at the same commit level as the latest commit of the working branch.  However, it doesn't handle when the working branch may already be based on master, but is several commits ahead of master.  Any ideas?

Comment: Which branch are you doing `show-ref` on?  It should be master.  Basically the two commands are to check and see if the latest commit on master is the merge-base for the working branch.  The commits that are on the working branch shouldn't matter at all.