# Is it possible to check if a rebase is required in a GitLab merge request pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to perform some technical checks on other systems before I can allow branches to be rebased in GitLab. This is why I want to add a pipeline step to the merge request to perform these checks in case a rebase is required. Is it possible to check if a rebase is required in the pipeline? I didn't find any CI variable for this use case.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit March 2023

@ConjuringCoffee tested my solution and it didn't work, but they found [a way to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74629163/4104396)... if you happen to end up on my solution first, just skip ahead to theirs.

---

## Original Post

As far as I know there is no GitLab way to check whether or not a branch needs to be rebased.

Basing this response on [this previous StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30177226/4104396), I would suggest trying to use Git on the command line to determine if a rebase is required:

```yaml
job:
  script:
    - export BRANCH_NAME=$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - hash1=$(git show-ref --heads -s $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH)
    - hash2=$(git merge-base $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH $BRANCH_NAME)
    - |
      if [[ "${hash1}" = "${hash2}" ]]; then
        echo "No rebase is not required"
      else
        echo "A rebase is required"
      fi
```

I have not tested this myself. Please notify me if this fails.

Comment: Hi Austin, this unfortunately didn't work for me, but it got me on the right track. Both git commands didn't work for me. I never got "show-ref" to work within the pipeline, and merge-base worked after I included origin/. I'm posting my solution in a separate answer due to the character limit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74629163/19697187

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Austin's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74144068/19697187) I ended up with this script:

```
  script:
  - LATEST_ON_TARGET_BRANCH=$(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H" origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME)
  - echo "Latest commit on the target branch is $LATEST_ON_TARGET_BRANCH"
  - COMMON_ANCESTOR=$(git merge-base origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME)
  - echo "Common ancestor of source and target branch is $COMMON_ANCESTOR"
  - |
    if [[ "${LATEST_ON_TARGET_BRANCH}" = "${COMMON_ANCESTOR}" ]]; then
      echo "The source branch is up to date with the target branch"
    else
      echo "The source branch is not up to date with the target branch"
      exit 1
    fi
```